# Could not find driver Laravel

Tags: laravel

Sorry for bad english.
I've been trying to fix this error in Laravel "could not find driver".
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rlch9.png)

I'm using wampserver. Please help me

[configuration .env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCyuV.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to add a bit more details.
Which database you're using (MySQL, ...) and how did you try to configure that in Laravel? Thanks!

Comment: What are the configurations used in your .env? Can you add them to the question. e.g HOST, DB etc

Comment: Hello! This is my configuration                                
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=booking
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

Answer (score 1):

I created a file with the code

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

PDO drivers exist. 
[PDO drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIrHm.png)

In my php.ini file i have this extension

```
extension=pdo_mysql
```

It's the first time i use Laravel :/ 
I couldn't find the solution

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is when you haven't installed php-mysql extension with your wamp installation of PHP. Take a look at your php configuration and enable it.

Comment: the php-mysql extension is installed bro

Answer (score 0):

Create a file containing the following code

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

check it in your browser (for example: http://localhost/test.php)

then serach PDO drivers in this page (CTRL + F and type PDO).

1- If you don't see  PDO drivers, You should add it , in your php.ini

```
"extension=pdo_mysql.dll"
```

2- Restart your Apache